# Route HTTP packets into tun/tap interface

Tags: iptables, route, packet

What I simply want is to redirect all HTTP packet from any interface to my tun/tap interface. A scapy script will listen on this interface and do some treatments to these packets.

First, I created a tun/tap interface:

```
sudo ip tuntap add mode tap tt0
```

I assigned an IP address as follow:

```
ifconfig tt0 10.0.0.1
```

Then, I added a mark with iptables as follow:

```
sudo iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

I made a rule to route marked packet through table 2:

```
ip rule add fwmark 1 table 2
```

Finnaly, I added the route to the tt0 interface created above:

```
ip route add default via 10.0.0.1 table 2
```

A simple "curl google.com" will normally generate an HTTP request, and I should be able to see that packet with wireshark if I listen to the tt0 interface right?
In fact, this is not the case...no traffic is present on tt0. Do I miss something?
Thanks.

Comment: I must add that my eth0 interface is on another subnet. Is that a problem?

Comment: You try to use your own ip as gateway.

Comment: Hello, thanks for you answer. I try to use tt0 as my gateway indeed. My principal interface is eth0 at 192.168.0.6. My second interface is tt0 at 10.0.0.1 on the same server. What I want is to route HTTP traffic from eth0 to * via tt0, and see them in wireshark if I listen to "tto" interface.

Comment: Use the endpoint of your tt0 as gateway.

Comment: I understand what you mean, however I don't have any endpoint for my tt0. It was just created via "ip tuntap add " and random private ip attributed via "ifconfig" as a virtual interface. My goal was to route all HTTP traffic through that interface and get packets with wireshark that listen on it. Do you mean that without any valid endpoint, I could not sniff anything on it?